# How do I remove all split windows from tmux session?

Tags: tmux

I keep seeing extra splits in my tmux session and it is driving me crazy when trying to copy and paste out logs, it copies the columns!

Comment: If you enable mouse support with `:set mouse`, selections respect pane boundaries.

Comment: You can also use `<prefix>-z` to toggle between the full window and only the current pane.

Comment: The way you've phrased it sounds like these are splits that you didn't create (the phrase 'extra splits' makes it sound like you're surprised by their existence)? Maybe an image would help clarify what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

You run the command `CTRL+b` and then type the subcommand `:kill-pane -a`.

Preview of what that looks like here:

[image: kill-pane sub command]